# Eclipse C++: fatal error: cheddar.h: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, path, include

[RHEL v7.3, Eclipse Photon, C/C++ Project with Eclipse-generated Makefile]

Attempting to include a custom library named `cheddar.h` results in 
`Fatal Error: cheddar.h: no such file or directory`

Research [1](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_proj_paths.htm) and [2](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/263075/) suggests manually adding the include path by first alt-clicking the project in Project Explorer, and then manually adding the path :
`Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols : Includes : Languages, GNU C++`

No luck.

It works if I do things the old-fashioned way, and add the path to the makefile with a -I option, like so
`-I/home/kmiklas/lib/`

..but I feel like I'm working-around the issue, and I want this set up properly; the way it **should** be set up.

How do I correctly specify a custom include path in Eclipse? Tyvm :^)

Comment: If you have a "project with makefile" doesn't that mean that you don't want Eclipse to mess around with settings and just use make instead?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse internal build, external build with Eclipse-generated makefiles, or some other build type?

Comment: And is Eclipse able to find and index your `cheddar.h` file?

Comment: ^^^ External build with Eclipse-generated makefile, which I edited with the -I option.

Comment: @FredLarson, perhaps I misunderstand. If I specify a Makefile, does this sidestep and invalidate ``Properties`` settings described above?

Comment: Adding the include path as your Research 1 and 2 suggested is the right way. Did you make sure you specified it for the build configuration your actually using? Do you have multiple build configurations specified?

Comment: If you're using a makefile not generated by Eclipse, adding the path within Eclipse will not affect the include path used to build. It will affect the indexer.

Comment: Build Configuration is set to ``Default [Active]`` as shown in ``Properties -> C/C++ Build`` screen.

Answer (score 1):

## What is wrong with CMake/Makefile?

I don’t know, but this just sounds like an XY problem. But what’s even more confusing is how you’re so reluctant to use a solution that you’ve already got (as in it’s bugging me).

### ***Anyway***

What may aid you in this is to ditch eclipse’s settings and just use the compiler’s. Eclipse uses (GCC/G++ (probably)). What you can do is set some *environment variables DUN DUN DUHH*!

These environment variables are aptly named: `C_INCLUDE_PATH` and `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`. If, however, you want the same for both (you want to use it for both languages) you can just set `CPATH`.

You’re probably thinking: what else can I do with this marvel... and for that I direct you to [the official GCC website](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Environment-Variables.html#Environment-Variables).

Comment: If you must know, the ``X`` in this XY problem is the use of **VIM** as the primary editor. Don't get me wrong, VIM has it's place, and is great for a quick look at files, but there's only so much ``gdb`` I can take before I want a modern IDE, so I'm trying to nurture us onto **Eclipse**. Think notepad++ vs Visual Studio in Windows, or TextWrangler vs Xcode on a Mac.

Comment: **Anyway**, it seems that I have three (3) solutions here: 1. Use a Makefile _not_ generated by Eclipse with the ``-I`` option to specify target directories; 2. Use the Eclipse build system, and specify paths therein. 3. Set environment variables (*gasp*), as you suggest. The problem with (3) is that this code will be committed to source control, and I want User to be able to build with minimal environment setup. I suppose I could ask them to set up their environment variables, and/or write a little script to do so... but I fear that it's too much to ask.

Comment: Are you generating the makefile with cmake? You can do the CXX_COMPILER_FLAGS option if you are, or you can use it in your makefile. if they aren't libraries that already exist you're going to want to put them in the same project so the users can get the code to compile. If not you'll have them as dependencies and they'll compile to their respective locations.